# What does Scanner.hasnext() return, if it is called on closed Scanner?

Tags: java

see example:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(...);
s.close();
println(s.hasnext());
```

Will this command print true or false or will it show an error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The obvious answer in this case is "try it for yourself". Stack Overflow is intended to be a bit of last resort, after you've researched a problem for yourself.

Comment: If you can write the example, why not compile and run it to find out?  Or, why not look up the method's documentation which clearly states what will happen?

Comment: What does it output when you tried it  (by creating a new class and including this code in the main() method ) on your IDE like eclipse ? You should see hasNext documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

As per java doc of the method it throws an exception.

> Throws:
>       IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed